# Google Cloud Storage bucket not readable. (CloudStorageStreamWrapper::stream_open call failed)

Tags: google-app-engine, laravel, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to read/write Laravel blade templates to a Google Cloud Storage bucket.

The compiled templates are correctly writing to the bucket, but when the view attempts to read the compiled template back out of the bucket I get the following error:

> include(gs://my-site.appspot.com/views/c08e5794b1fc664fce0cd30fc8e7898e):
>   failed to open stream:
>   "\google\appengine\ext\cloud_storage_streams\CloudStorageStreamWrapper::stream_open"
>   call failed

Why would the app be able to write to the bucket successfully but then fail to read back out?

Comment: Here you can find sample code to read/write GCS files and create serving url's for templates with or without a blob_key: https://github.com/voscausa/appengine-gcs-blobstore-python

Comment: More specifically, it doesn't work because 'include' doesn't understand 'gs://' URLs. Using voscausa's link above you can create a serving URL which will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to include files from the bucket, add to your php.ini:

```
google_app_engine.allow_include_gs_buckets = "views"
```

Comment: thanks, I used the full bucket name instead. I needed for fopen